# no element type exists with getCriteria and custom element type

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, elementcriteriamodel, models, custom

I am working on a plugin using the getCriteria function, but for every Element Type I put, I always get an error:

> No element type exists by the type “Comerce_Group”.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria("Comerce_Group");
$criteria->number = $number;
return $criteria->first();
```

And here is the Comerce_Group code:

```
class Comerce_GroupModel extends BaseModel
{  
    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array (
            'id' => AttributeType::Number,
            'number' => AttributeType::String,
            'itemTotal' => AttributeType::Number,
        );
    }    
}
```

Comment: That's not an ElementType, that's just a model. What is it you're trying to achieve? Chances are, you don't actually need a custom ElementType.

Answer (score 1):

As [Stephen](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20732/no-element-type-exists-with-getcriteria-and-custom-element-type/20740#comment27848_20732) pointed out, you're getting that error because your `Commerce_GroupModel` class is a [Model](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/models) that extends `BaseModel`, not an [Element](https://pixelandtonic.com/blog/craft-element-types) [Type](https://straightupcraft.com/events/introduction-to-element-types-in-craft-cms-part-1-of-3), which is what `ElementsService->getCriteria()` is looking for.

Are you sure you actually need a custom element type here?  Depending on what you're going for, Models might be enough.

Comment: i wish to search the commerce groups and then return the one with a specific identification number to see if it exist and then further process it , i wanted to avoid doing this though DB querys, i got the idea while looking over the Craft Commerce plugin

Comment: Assuming you've got a `Commerce_GroupRecord` defined in your plugin that tied to to a database table for persistent storage?